# Why am I not getting a password prompt when running a command as sudo, even though my user's group isn't even in the sudoers file?

Tags: sudo, freebsd, root

I'm in `/etc` which has the following the permissions:

```
drwxr-xr-x  23 root  wheel  2560 Jul  1 20:47 etc

$ whoami
pierre
$ groups
pierre
```

I have to run `sudo` if I want to `touch foo` in `/etc`.

What I want is to be prompted for `root`'s password, but I don't get prompted, even after changing this line:

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

in `sudo visudo` to:

```
%wheel ALL=(ALL) PASSWD: ALL
```

It shouldn't even matter though, considering my current user is not in group `wheel`...  I've made sure that the `root` account has a password set (by setting it using `sudo passwd root`).

I'm on a FreeBSD 10.3-RELEASE-p11 cloud server.

Any insight on why I'm not getting prompted for a password is greatly appreciated!

Here is my suoders file *after* adding the line suggested in @jesse_b's answer.

```
## sudoers file.
##
## This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
## Failure to use 'visudo' may result in syntax or file permission errors
## that prevent sudo from running.
##
## See the sudoers man page for the details on how to write a sudoers file.
##

##
## Host alias specification
##
## Groups of machines. These may include host names (optionally with wildcards),
## IP addresses, network numbers or netgroups.
# Host_Alias    WEBSERVERS = www1, www2, www3

##
## User alias specification
##
## Groups of users.  These may consist of user names, uids, Unix groups,
## or netgroups.
# User_Alias    ADMINS = millert, dowdy, mikef

##
## Cmnd alias specification
##
## Groups of commands.  Often used to group related commands together.
# Cmnd_Alias    PROCESSES = /usr/bin/nice, /bin/kill, /usr/bin/renice, \
#               /usr/bin/pkill, /usr/bin/top
# Cmnd_Alias    REBOOT = /sbin/halt, /sbin/reboot, /sbin/poweroff

##
## Defaults specification
##
## Uncomment if needed to preserve environmental variables related to the
## FreeBSD pkg utility and fetch.
# Defaults     env_keep += "PKG_CACHEDIR PKG_DBDIR FTP_PASSIVE_MODE"
##
## Additionally uncomment if needed to preserve environmental variables
## related to portupgrade
# Defaults     env_keep += "PORTSDIR PORTS_INDEX PORTS_DBDIR PACKAGES PKGTOOLS_CONF"
##
## You may wish to keep some of the following environment variables
## when running commands via sudo.
##
## Locale settings
# Defaults env_keep += "LANG LANGUAGE LINGUAS LC_* _XKB_CHARSET"
##
## Run X applications through sudo; HOME is used to find the
## .Xauthority file.  Note that other programs use HOME to find   
## configuration files and this may lead to privilege escalation!
# Defaults env_keep += "HOME"
##
## X11 resource path settings
# Defaults env_keep += "XAPPLRESDIR XFILESEARCHPATH XUSERFILESEARCHPATH"
##
## Desktop path settings
# Defaults env_keep += "QTDIR KDEDIR"
##
## Allow sudo-run commands to inherit the callers' ConsoleKit session
# Defaults env_keep += "XDG_SESSION_COOKIE"
##
## Uncomment to enable special input methods.  Care should be taken as
## this may allow users to subvert the command being run via sudo.
# Defaults env_keep += "XMODIFIERS GTK_IM_MODULE QT_IM_MODULE QT_IM_SWITCHER"
##
## Uncomment to use a hard-coded PATH instead of the user's to find commands
# Defaults secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"
##
## Uncomment to send mail if the user does not enter the correct password.
# Defaults mail_badpass
##
## Uncomment to enable logging of a command's output, except for
## sudoreplay and reboot.  Use sudoreplay to play back logged sessions.
# Defaults log_output
# Defaults!/usr/bin/sudoreplay !log_output
# Defaults!/usr/local/bin/sudoreplay !log_output
# Defaults!REBOOT !log_output

##
## Runas alias specification
##
Defaults rootpw
##
## User privilege specification
##
root ALL=(ALL) ALL

## Uncomment to allow members of group wheel to execute any command
# %wheel ALL=(ALL) ALL

## Same thing without a password
%wheel ALL=(ALL) PASSWD: ALL

## Uncomment to allow members of group sudo to execute any command
# %sudo ALL=(ALL) ALL

## Uncomment to allow any user to run sudo if they know the password
## of the user they are running the command as (root by default).
# Defaults targetpw  # Ask for the password of the target user
# ALL ALL=(ALL) ALL  # WARNING: only use this together with 'Defaults targetpw'

## Read drop-in files from /usr/local/etc/sudoers.d
## (the '#' here does not indicate a comment)
#includedir /usr/local/etc/sudoers.d
```

Comment: are there files in /usr/local/etc/sudoers.d ?

Comment: You should be editing `/usr/local/etc/sudoers`.

Comment: @Jeff... you hit the nail on the head :)  Would you like to post an answer?

Comment: @arrowd, I checked `/usr/local/etc/sudoers` and verified that my edits via `sudo visudo` were indeed getting saved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a non-obvious syntax, since it looks like a comment, but sudoers allows you to include rules in another directory with the directive:

```
#includedir /usr/local/etc/sudoers.d
```

It is likely that your nopasswd rule exists in a file in that directory.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following line to `/etc/sudoers`:

```
Defaults rootpw
```

I think sudo normally prompts for that current user's password so long as the user is a member of the wheel group.

Comment: After reading about this in `man sudoers`, I added it thinking it would work.  I also did a restart of the server - but no luck.  I still am able to execute `sudo touch foo` without a password prompt.  I also read in the man page the following: `By default, sudo requires that a user authenticate him or herself before running a command.  This behavior can be modified via the NOPASSWD tag.`  As my user isn't even part of any groups mentioned in the sudoers file, I would expect that the default would be as explained in the man page...  :(

Comment: is it actually creating the file in /etc ? and if so what if you remove the file and try again?

Comment: Yes, it's creating foo, and i immediately do a sudo rm foo each time.  I also double-verified by doing sudo vim foo and edited it and saved successfully.